# How do I get rid of the fullcalendar.io top line scroll bar?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

fullcalendar.io has a scroll bar on the right hand side of the header and I am wondering how to get rid of it?

If you go to https://fullcalendar.io/demos and click "Resource Timeline" you will see this on the first line in the top right.

I am wondering if there is a configuration option to get rid of it.

Also, what is the purpose of it, it doesn't seem to do anything?

[image]

Comment: I don't know but I suspect it's there because the lower scrollbar underneath is there too, something to do with height of areas. If, for example, you set `contentHeight: "auto"` they will both go away (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/contentHeight). If you think it's a big problem, see https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Comment: Thanks, that works but I only want to get rid of the top scroll bar if possible.

Comment: There's no option for that currently AFAIK. Like I said, https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs. Or possibly https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features depending on your perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with css:

```
thead .fc-scroller {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```